# Need Some Hints on How to Simplify Further for Set Question

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I am given $(A ∪ (B − C)) ∪ (C − (A ∩ B))$

I used De Morgans Law and the Distributive Law, but I ran into a roadblock where I could not simplify any further. I got to:

$((A ∪ B) ∩ (A ∪ C')) ∪ ((C ∩ A') ∪ (C ∩ B'))$

Any tips on how to proceed? I did draw a Venn diagram and got a rough idea of what I should be headed towards, but I don't see a way how to get there.

Answer (score 3):

We can use the identities $C\backslash (A \cap B)=C\backslash A \cup C\backslash B$ and $A \cup C\backslash A = A\cup C$.

Then $A \cup B \backslash C \cup C \backslash (A \cap B)= \\
A \cup B \backslash C \cup C \backslash A \cup C \backslash B = \\
A \cup C \cup B \backslash C \cup C \backslash B = \\
A \cup C \cup B \cup C \backslash B = \\
A \cup C \cup B \cup C  = \\
A \cup B \cup C$

Edit: To prove the identities, you need to "element chase" which should not be too hard...

Comment: If $x \in A \cap B \cap C$ then $x \in A$ and so $x \in A \cup B \backslash C$ and so  $x \in (A \cup B \backslash C) \cup (C \backslash (A \cap B)) $

Answer (score 0):

Well, I use common sense.

All of $A$ must be in that set because $A \subset A\cup anything \subset (A\cup anything) \cup anything$

Since all of $A$ is in that set then all of $A\cap B$ is in that set.  So when we consider $C- (A\cap B)$ we don't have to reject the $A\cap$ be as we are just going to include it with $A\cup (B-c)$.

So our set can be simplified to $(A \cup (B-C)) \cup C$.

Now we know our set contains all of $C$ so when we considered $B-C$ we don't have to throw out the elements of $C$ as we will just add them when we union with $C$.

So our set can be simplified to $A\cup B \cup C$.

Which is.... surprising.

If that is not convincing we can element chase.

If $x \in A$ then $x \in A \subset A\cup (B-C) \subset (A\cup (B-C)) \cup (C-(A\cap B)$.

If $x \in B$ then either $x \in A$ or $x\not \in A$, we already shown $x \in $ our set.  If $x\not \in A$ then $x\not \in A\cap B$.  Either $x \in C$ or $x\not \in C$.  If $x \in C$ then $x\in C-(A\cap B)\subset (A\cup(B-C))\cup (C-(A\cap B))$.  And if $x \not \in C$ then $x \in B-C$ so $x\in B-C\subset (A\cup (B-C)) \subset  (A\cup (B-C)) \cup (C-(A\cap B)$.  So in all casese if $x \in B$ the $x\in$ our set.

If $x \in C$ we've already shown $x$ is in our set if $x$ is in either $B$ or $A$.  If $x$ is not in either then $x \in A\cap B$ and so $x \in C-(A\cap B)\subset  (A\cup (B-C)) \cup (C-(A\cap B)$.

So if $x$ is in any of $A,B,$ or $C$ then $x \in $ our set and $(A\cup B \cup C)$ is a subset of our set.

Going the other way.

If $x \in  (A\cup (B-C)) \cup (C-(A\cap B)$ then either

$x\in A\cup (B-C)$ or $x \in (C-(A\cap B)$.

If $x \in A\cup B-C$ either $x \in A$ or $x \in B-C \subset B$.  So $x \in A\cup B \subset A\cup B \cup C$.

And if $x \in C-(A\cap B)$ the $x \in C-(A\cap B) \subset C \subset A\cup B\cup C$.

So our set is a subset of $A\cup B\cup C$.

So our set is $A\cup B\cup C$.

...

Also we can do this by considering the 8 basic partitions of $A,B,C$.  That is there are eight disjoint sets that cover all possibilities.  They are $A^{\sim}\cap B^{\sim} \cap C^{\sim}$ where $A^{\sim}$ can be either $A$ or $A'$.

Call our set $X$.

$A\cap B\cap C\subset X$ because $A\cap B\cap C\subset A \subset X$.

The same is true for $A\cap B \cap C', A\cap B'\cap C, A\cap B'\cap C'$.

$A'\cap B\cap C$ is disjoint from $A\cap B$ but is a subset of $C$ so is a subset of $C-(A\cap B) \subset X$.  Same is true of $A'\cap B'\cap C$.

$A'\cap B\cap C'$ is a subset of $B\cap C'=B- C \subset A\cup (B-C) \subset X$.

The eighth and final partion to consider is $A'\cap B'\cap C'$.  It is disjoint from $C$ so disjoint from $C-(A\cap B)$.  It is disjoint for $B$ so disjoint from $B-C$.  And it is disjoint from $A$.  So it is disjoint from $(A\cup (B- C))$ and from $(A\cup (B-C)\cup (C-(A\cap B))$.

So $X$ consists of all seven partitions that are contained in any of $A,B$ or $C$ but none of the part that is in none.  So $X = A\cup B \cup C$.